# How would i write my map/soql query outside of the for loop?

Tags: apex, trigger, class

```
public static void oppFldUpdates(List<Opportunity> newOpps, Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMapps){
        Opportunity oldOpp = new Opportunity();  

 for (Opportunity newOpp :newOpps){                   


        set<Id> oppId = new Set<Id>();
        map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Region__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN : oppId]);
        list<Opportunity> oppslist = new list<Opportunity>();
                if(oldOpps.Install_at_Region__c == null){
                    newOpps.Install_at_Region__c = accMap.get(oldOpps.Install_At__c).Region__c;

            }
```

So this is a small snippet of a much larger class.

but the Install_At__c field is the reference field that I'm using between opportunity and account.

I'm trying to update the Opportunity.Install_at_Region__c text field with the Account.Region__c text field. and yes i can't write a new trigger or use a workflow etc etc.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that you have? If it is, I wouldn't expect your query to return _any_ results because 1) Your `oppId` Set is empty as it is just declared on the line before the query and 2) An `Account` Id will never be a match for an `Opportunity` Id. If you tried to obfuscate your code, please don't do that. I don't think anybody here is looking to "steal" your code (beyond some poor schlup trying to blindly copy/paste to try to fix their own issues), and you'll probably just confuse the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track, but you don't populate the set `oppId`, and that's what seems to be tripping you up. The key is that you need *two* `for` loops, unless you already have a collection of the parent-object Ids you want to query.

So here you'd pull that `Set` declaration out of your `for` loop, and iterate over `newOpps` to populate it:

```
set<Id> oppId = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity newOpp : newOpps) {
     oppId.add(newOpp.AccountId);
}
```

Then you pull that query out of the `for` loop too:

```
Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Region__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN : oppId]);
```

(Note that this will work now, because we populated `oppId` with the Ids of all the Accounts we want).

Once you've done that, you can use something like the structure you already have: you iterate over your `newOpps` list again, use the `Map` to get the field you need from the Opportunity's parent Account, and update the Opportunity. Make sure to run the `update` DML outside of the loop.

I'm not sure about that `oldMap` logic you have inside the `for` loop. If this is running in an `update` trigger, it doesn't make much sense to control the functionality based on the *old* value in that field. If it's running in an `after update` trigger, the sObjects in `newOpps` are going to be read-only, so you'd have to fire another `update` DML.

Comment: +1 Without event that for loop he can just use the new map keyset() to querry!

Comment: +1, but there is a one-liner that gets rid of the first for loop: `Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Region__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountID FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :newOpps)]);`

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you have any sense if there's a performance penalty if one goes for the sub-select rather than iterating in Apex? (I've never benchmarked it, and just assumed cavalierly that I'd rather Apex it).

Comment: @DavidReed There's a performance *benefit*, actually; you'll slightly reduce your CPU time and heap space used, plus the code is more compact (typically translates as "more readable"). It's not a significant make-or-break type benefit, but I prefer not to make my code longer than necessary.